# Laravel 8 jetsream 'user/profile' endpoint doesnt show name & email on SPA mode (turbolinks)

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, turbolinks, laravel-livewire

I activated SPA mode on Laravel 8 Jetstream Livewire, I found `name` and `email` been empty when I click `user/profile` endpoint from other page, it will show the `name` and `email` when I refresh the browser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Turbolinks/Turbo AND Livewire on the same page, this plugin is required.

Livewire Version 1 supported Turbolinks internally. Livewire Version 2 has removed internal support and extracted it into this plugin.

so in (/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) just put this script after               @livewireScripts

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/livewire/turbolinks@v0.1.x/dist/livewire-turbolinks.js" data-turbolinks-eval="false" data-turbo-eval="false"></script>
```